# How to create following triangle view in android dynamically?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

[image]

Its been a dynamic view for each new entry a triangle is been added in list at bottom. How this can be created ? Any suggestion how to proceed ? How to create a custom layout-manager for it

Comment: i suggest to use single list item with image View and then with different PNG traingles based on need.

Comment: view are square in shape in android. if i use single list item with imageview. this view cannot be created i want second row to be overlap on the first row ...but how to do that while inflating layout

Answer (score 1):

Its Better to Use GridView with Two columns to acheive with PNG Images
[image]

Using These Png Images for First Two u can Use 3 and 4 and Then from There for Left Column add image 5 for right Column add image 2 and So on based on Requirement.

The output will resemble something Like

[image]